# How to pass parameters from azure pipeline to shell script?

Tags: linux, azure, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to pass parameters to a shell script from an Azure pipeline.  The shell script is being hit, but the parameters aren't coming over.  Here is the pipeline task:

```
- task: AzureCLI@2
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'our-subscription'
    scriptType: 'bash'
    scriptLocation: 'scriptPath'
    scriptPath: 'Path/to/shellscript/cli.sh'
    arguments: 
    addSpnToEnvironment: 
      ${{ variables.appVersion }}
      ${{ variables.bNumber }}
```

Here is some of the cli.sh

```
appVersion=$1
buildNo=$2    
echo printing values:
echo appVersion= "$appVersion"
echo buildNo= "$buildNo"
```

Here is some of the log within the pipeline task

```
printing values: 
appVersion=  
buildNo=  
D:\a\1\s\path\to\shellscript\cli.sh: line 72: wget: command not found
```

Also note that the wget command is not being recognized either.  What am I missing?

Comment: Did you look at the documentation for examples of how to specify arguments? Your `arguments` parameter is empty and it looks like you're trying to pass them via `addSpnToEnvironment`, which I'm honestly surprised is even syntactically valid. `wget` not being found is probably because `wget` isn't installed on the agent you're using.

Comment: My colleague was using the addSpnToEnv method.  I switched to the -task ShellScript@2 task and now the parameters are coming over.  I'm using a linux agent so I assumed wget was already installed.  When I ssh into the vmss instance and run the script manually from there, it works.  Maybe I'm confusing agent with vm.  Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 7):

Usage of "addSpnToEnvironment" is to add service principal ID and key of the Azure endpoint you chose to the script's execution environment.

***addSpnToEnvironment
Access service principal details in script  (Optional) Adds service principal ID and key of the Azure endpoint you chose to the script's execution environment. You can use these variables: $env:servicePrincipalId, $env:servicePrincipalKey and $env:tenantId in your script. This is honored only when the Azure endpoint has Service Principal authentication scheme
Default value: false***

And in your task you are trying to passing variables through this property which is syntactically not valid and here is what you can do to achieve the result you are looking for:

For quick test i passed your script as inline script instead of passing the script path.

```
variables:
- name: appVersion
  value: 1.0
- name: bNumber
  value: $(Build.BuildNumber)
steps:
- task: AzureCLI@2
  inputs:
    azureSubscription:'<subscription>'
    scriptType: 'bash'
    scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
    inlineScript: |
      #!/bin/sh
      appVersion=$1
      buildNo=$2    
      echo printing values:
      echo appVersion= "$appVersion"
      echo buildNo= "$buildNo"
    arguments: '${{ variables.appVersion }} ${{ variables.bNumber }}'
```

Pipeline output:

```
printing values:
appVersion= 1.0
buildNo= 20220223.16
/usr/bin/az account clear
Finishing: AzureCLI
```